# Magento crashes .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I have Magento instaled on shared hosting plan from godaddy, it keeps on crashing, I think it's because of the .htaccess file.
MY htaccess file is http://pastebin.com/qUs1SDL3

Comment: Did you check the web server logs? Also what do you see in the browser  ... is it blank screen or you see some error message?

Comment: Sometimes I see this error - 1)General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away"  & sometimes 2) Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111"

Comment: Sometimes I get 500 internal server error & sometimes it takes a while to load the page.

Comment: Regarding the error "General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away", it looks more like sever configuration error. I suggest you to contact the support of your shared hosting ... sometimes they just change the configuration and it "breaks" Magento.

Comment: error `Mysql server has gone away` means that Mysql need more `max_allowed_packet` in order to accomplish current task. I have seen this error when Magento tries to insert cascading queries `insert into tbl values(), (), () ..` that goes on beyond the allowed limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not install Magento on a shared host and expect it to work, least of all GoDaddy.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, making key_buffer and max_allowed_packet 16M usually solves this issue